# One single git repository for 2 different heroku apps with different PROCFILES, is it possible?

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, websocket, autobahn

I want to create **2 different heroku apps**.Both are using **same github repo**sitory. Each app is having different processes to run i.e they need **2 different PROCFILES**. Can we use same github code for runnning 2 different apps ?

I created 2 different apps on Heroku. In Github code, created 2 different Procfiles also. In environment variables of each heroku app, I explicitly specifed 'PROCFILE' as environment variable with path of PROCFILE for each app. For one app i kept name of PROCFILE as it is and for other I created one different folder 'Backend' and in that folder added PROCFILE.

**Example of my folder structure:**

```
Project_folder\
    -PROCFILE --> For one app
    -my_code_folder\
        -abc.py
        -xyz.py
    -Backend\
        -PROCFILE --> For second app
```